# Symfony-PHP | How to create domain redirection to my apps user subdomain?

Tags: php, symfony1, dns, subdomain

I have application that let user create their own website. Every user separate using subdomain for example

my application url example.com, my user create their website in url user.example.com

my user having their own domain user.com, and I want to facilitate him change their website url from user.example.com into user.com

How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much..

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way it is usually set up with popular platforms is that people have to set up their own domain and then point that domain per A-Record to your servers IP.

That basically means that everyone who enters the domain name in their browsers will end up on your server.

The next step would require the user to enter their domain name in their profile. You can then check the "incoming" domain and lookup the user for that domain - I dont know how your controllers and routing are set up, but you would then have to route these requests to the users profile page.